# Run two AWS methods in the same function of AWS Lambda code

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, aws-lambda, async.js

I am creating an AWS Lambda script to retrieve information of my AWS account. At present I am having an issue in the function 3, i want to retrieve the users that have a policy, in this case i run the method to retrieve the list users and then run the method to retrieve the policy based on the users input and send it to an array to the callback. The issue is that the callback is empty. I have tested by console.log(userpolicies); and it is ok in the second method but when it out of the second method the userpolicies is in blank.

I understand that the issue is because i have two aws method in the same function but I don't how to solve.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

```
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var async = require('async');
    var stackoverflow = (event, context, callback) => {
        var iam = new AWS.IAM();
        async.series([
            //function1
            function(callback) {
                iam.listGroups(function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        callback(err);
                    } else 
                        callback(null, data);
                    });
            },
            //function2
            function(callback) {
                iam.listPolicies(function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        callback(err);
                    } else 
                        callback(null, data);
                    });
            },
            //function3
            function(callback) {
                var userpolicies = [];
                iam.listUsers(function(err,data) {
                    if (err)
                        console.log(err);
                    else
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.Users.length; i++) {
                            var params = {UserName: data.Users[i].UserName};
                            iam.listAttachedUserPolicies(params, function(err1, data1){
                                if (err1)
                                    console.log(err1);
                                else
                                for (var j = 0; j < data1.AttachedPolicies.length; j ++) {
                                    var infopolicies = '{"PolicyName":"'+data1.AttachedPolicies[j].PolicyName+'"}';
                                    var infopoliciesjson = JSON.parse(infopolicies);
                                    userpolicies.push(infopoliciesjson);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    callback(null, userpolicies);
                });
            }
    ], callback);
    };
exports.handler = stackoverflow;
```

Comment: You aren't passing any request parameters to any of the `iam.xxx()` methods, just callback functions.  It's not clear how this code could work at all.

Comment: There are methods where the param is optional and other where is required, for instance: listPolicies, listGroups  and listUsers the param is optional but for listAttachedUserPolicies we need to enter the username.